# How do I see how much bandwidth my VoIP phone takes?

Tags: voip

I have a VoIP Phone with Vonage where highspeed internet service with rogers. More recently my internet bandwith usage has gone up even though I am not suring internet that much (2.5 - 3 GB per day). I am just wondering how much bandwith VoIP takes. Does the VoIP phone uses bandwith only when I am talking on phone?

Answer (score 3):

The stock figures for a VoIP connection using a plain vanilla G.711 CODEC and well-compressed G.729 are:

- G.711 is approx 76.6MB per hour full duplex
- G.729 is approx 27.4MB per hour full duplex

Which, I am told, means using your VoIP phone with a G.711 CODEC for one hour a day is about 2.3GB per month.

More info at: http://www.dslreports.com/faq/12190

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually VoIP will make some call to server for gathering some infos, but it's a few KB per day, not GB.

Answer (score 0):

Voip phones use about 100 kbps up and down during a call and they will use some bandwidth when first plugged in for registration purposes. Also, they will re-register every so often as well, but this is minimal communication.

Answer (score 0):

There are two channels used per VoIP call. One is upload channel (talking) and the download channel (listening). Assuming, you and the person you are talking to take turns talking, then we can assume your telephone call is using approximately a maximum of 110 Kbps.

There are various aspects you can check your bandwidth before installing the VoIP service. Make sure the following tests before choosing a service provider:

Run a speed test on your network;
Rrun the extended test to test the ping;
Check for packet loss
Determine your concurrent call volume

Source:http://www.phoneam.com/